# DKIM configuration on Debian

Tags: email, spam-prevention, postfix, mail-server, dkim

Due to the fact that many e-mails we send with our company address do not get delivered, rejected or marked as spam, I searched for a solution on the web.

One of the solutions I found was to use DKIM on my mail server, so I set it up using this guide (http://linuxaria.com/howto/using-opendkim-to-sign-postfix-mails-on-debian).

I tested my configuration by sending an e-mail to my gmail address, but I think something went wrong:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@mycompany.com designates [IP-ADDRESS] as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@mycompany.com;
   dkim=neutral (bad format) header.i=@mycompany.com
Received: by mail.mycompany.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
id 0AD9D2841B4C; Tue,  3 Dec 2013 10:30:51 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=mycompany.com; s=mail;
t=1386063052; bh=A3KLcdiP7ZMwPprgmvkJy01tx3mp6kKlCIuik8lKKnE=;
h=Subject:From:Content-type:To:Message-Id:Date;
b=cUbSyWpGBoa26Jkg9zer9XhxFmrhiQ49MOmP9nE2W5GNQlZYwyBt+jGbzaHIO1yFT
 A8lugRxXzH1EsS/ymkBqsx0HBCzSpn8PK0ya2gb90jydEleMa4had7Z3PuonbZ4Yw8
 fwcm4Zz+aZv2qYlLIT0ovhL+YI8pN14YJ7W6mpFA=
```

From what I can make out of it, something is wrong with the DKIM-signature itself, but I have no idea.

On a side note, is there any other way to prevent our mails getting blocked by spam filters?

Big thanks!
Rik

Answer (score 1):

I found the pickle! There was something wrong with my DNS record. Just copy the one that's generated in the mail.txt file when you generate your DKIM key. Also, it takes some time for the DNS (root) servers to account for the changes.